# Pandas take nearest value to the second and interpolate

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation, resampling

I'm looking to convert a data frame of the following format as an example:

```
>>>df
                      vals
2019-08-10 12:03:05   1.0
2019-08-10 12:03:06   NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:07   NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:08   3.0
2019-08-10 12:03:09   4.0
2019-08-10 12:03:10   NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:11   NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:12   5.0
2019-08-10 12:03:13   NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:14   1.0
2019-08-10 12:03:15   NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:16   NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:17   6.0
```

into one such as:

```
>>>df
                      vals
2019-08-10 12:03:05   1.0
2019-08-10 12:03:06   1.667
2019-08-10 12:03:07   2.333
2019-08-10 12:03:08   3.0
2019-08-10 12:03:09   3.667
2019-08-10 12:03:10   4.333
2019-08-10 12:03:11   5.0
2019-08-10 12:03:12   3.667
2019-08-10 12:03:13   2.333
2019-08-10 12:03:14   1.0
2019-08-10 12:03:15   2.667
2019-08-10 12:03:16   4.333
2019-08-10 12:03:17   6.0
```

Where the dataframe was first aligned to look like the following (taking the closest value to every 3rd value):

```
>>>df
                      vals
2019-08-10 12:03:05   1.0
2019-08-10 12:03:06   NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:07   NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:08   3.0
2019-08-10 12:03:09   NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:10   NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:11   5.0
2019-08-10 12:03:12   NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:13   NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:14   1.0
2019-08-10 12:03:15   NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:16   NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:17   6.0
```

And then linearly interpolated between each value to produce the final dataframe. Should there be a gap of more than 2 seconds, I'd like to just not interpolate between those 2 values.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
df.resample('3s').nearest()
```

Which produces:

```
>>> df.resample('3s').nearest()
                     vals
2019-08-10 12:03:03   1.0
2019-08-10 12:03:06   NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:09   4.0
2019-08-10 12:03:12   5.0
2019-08-10 12:03:15   NaN
```

Also:

```
>>> df.resample('2s').nearest()
                     vals
2019-08-10 12:03:04   1.0
2019-08-10 12:03:06   NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:08   3.0
2019-08-10 12:03:10   NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:12   5.0
2019-08-10 12:03:14   1.0
2019-08-10 12:03:16   NaN
```

Which makes it very clear that nearest is a complete lie, or at least a misnomer, because the nearest value to 10 is quite obviously 4. Also, the final value at `2019-08-10 12:03:16` should definitely be `6.0`.

This is just trying to align the values to the second, after this, simply `interpolate` seems to work.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `base` parameter for change offset of sampling period with modulo by `3` of first value of index (because 3 seconds) with [`Resampler.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.first.html):

```
df['new'] = df.resample('3s', base=df.index[0].second % 3).first()
print (df)
                     vals  new
2019-08-10 12:03:05   1.0  1.0
2019-08-10 12:03:06   NaN  NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:07   NaN  NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:08   3.0  3.0
2019-08-10 12:03:09   4.0  NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:10   NaN  NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:11   NaN  5.0
2019-08-10 12:03:12   5.0  NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:13   NaN  NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:14   1.0  1.0
2019-08-10 12:03:15   NaN  NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:16   NaN  NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:17   6.0  6.0
```

Then iterpolate:

```
df['new'] = df['new'].interpolate()
print (df)
                     vals       new
2019-08-10 12:03:05   1.0  1.000000
2019-08-10 12:03:06   NaN  1.666667
2019-08-10 12:03:07   NaN  2.333333
2019-08-10 12:03:08   3.0  3.000000
2019-08-10 12:03:09   4.0  3.666667
2019-08-10 12:03:10   NaN  4.333333
2019-08-10 12:03:11   NaN  5.000000
2019-08-10 12:03:12   5.0  3.666667
2019-08-10 12:03:13   NaN  2.333333
2019-08-10 12:03:14   1.0  1.000000
2019-08-10 12:03:15   NaN  2.666667
2019-08-10 12:03:16   NaN  4.333333
2019-08-10 12:03:17   6.0  6.000000
```

Testing with add 2 seconds to index:

```
df.index += pd.Timedelta(2, 's')
df['new'] = df.resample('3s', base=df.index[0].second % 3).first()
print (df)

                     vals  new
2019-08-10 12:03:07   1.0  1.0
2019-08-10 12:03:08   NaN  NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:09   NaN  NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:10   3.0  3.0
2019-08-10 12:03:11   4.0  NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:12   NaN  NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:13   NaN  5.0
2019-08-10 12:03:14   5.0  NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:15   NaN  NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:16   1.0  1.0
2019-08-10 12:03:17   NaN  NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:18   NaN  NaN
2019-08-10 12:03:19   6.0  6.0
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df1=df.set_index(['Time']).interpolate(method='linear').reset_index()
print(df1)
```

**Output**

```
                   Time     vals
0   2019-08-10 12:03:05     1.000000
1   2019-08-10 12:03:06     1.666667
2   2019-08-10 12:03:07     2.333333
3   2019-08-10 12:03:08     3.000000
4   2019-08-10 12:03:09     4.000000
5   2019-08-10 12:03:10     4.333333
6   2019-08-10 12:03:11     4.666667
7   2019-08-10 12:03:12     5.000000
8   2019-08-10 12:03:13     3.000000
9   2019-08-10 12:03:14     1.000000
10  2019-08-10 12:03:15     2.666667
11  2019-08-10 12:03:16     4.333333
12  2019-08-10 12:03:17     6.000000
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to replace nan value with nearest value then you can use interpolate

```
data['value'] = data['value'].interpolate(method='nearest')
```

Comment: you can use pass  parameter to interpolate method as per your requirement check in details on below link  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html